# Mapping from DataTable to custom model with property names different than column names

Tags: c#, model, datatable, automapper

In the application I am working on the data is acquired and returned in data sets. However, I want to make the application model-based, therefore I need to map data sets to my custom model classes. I have come across **[this](http://www.geekytidbits.com/automapper-with-datatables/)** way of converting data tables to custom model classes.

As I have no control on the data source that returns data sets, I cannot rename its column names. And still in the model class I want to use properties with names of my own convention.

The case is: say I have a model

```
class PersonModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and the source data table has columns named `Identificator`, `First_Name`, `Last_Name`. Is there a way to somehow bind corresponding labels and map the content of the data table to a collection of `PersonModel`?

Comment: While looking for something else, I stepped on this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555065
Honestly didn't give it an extensive reading, but it may be useful to you.

Comment: It looks like something I was asking. I need to check how much time-consuming this solution is. I have actually developed kind of a mapper that seems to have similar interface. I'm really curious how much faster is what you brought up. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you would create the mapping as follows:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, PersonModel>()                
.ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetInt32(src.GetOrdinal("Identificator"))))
.ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetString(src.GetOrdinal("First_Name"))))
.ForMember(dest => dest.LastName , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetString(src.GetOrdinal("Last_Name"))));
```

Then in your code you would create a data reader and map it:

```
// Get the data reader and store in dr variable

var people = Mapper.Map<IDataReader, List<PersonModel>>(dr);
```

Comment: This seems like a nice solution. However, I thought of something like attributes to my class properties to give them another name in the context of data tables so I never have to repeat this code. As you haven't mentioned anything like that, I guess such solution doesn't exist and yours is good. Thank you

Comment: No problem, I do know what you mean and your idea would be a good solution. I'm not sure how to do that though. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just an FYI
for `AutoMapper 8.0.0` and `AutoMapper.Data 3.0.0`

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddDataReaderMapping();

    cfg.CreateMap<IDataRecord, PersonModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetValue(src.GetOrdinal("Identificator"))))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetValue(src.GetOrdinal("First_Name"))))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetValue(src.GetOrdinal("Last_Name"))));
});
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

DataTable dt = GetDataTable();
var people = mapper.Map<IDataReader, List<PersonModel>>(dt.CreateDataReader());
```

Don't know why but must use `CreateMap<IDataRecord` instead of `CreateMap<IDataReader` to make it work

Reference:
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Data/issues/35

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the old fashioned way. Build a data access class that would retrieve the data handle the conversion and return your custom objects.

```
public static List<PersonModel> GetPeople()
{
    List<PersonModel> people = new List<PersonModel>();

    DataSet data = SomeMethodToGetTheDataSet();
    foreach(DataRow in data.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        PersonModel person = getPersonFromDataRow();
        people.Add(person);
    }
    return people;
}



private static PersonModel getPersonFromDataRow(DataRow row)
{
    PersonModel person = new PersonModel();
    person.ID = row.Field<int>("Identificator");
    person.FirstName = row.Field<string>("First_Name");
    person.LastName = row.Field<string>("Last_Name");
    return person;
}
```

This is just a quick example. you'll need to add error checking and try/catch blocks to prevent null reference exceptions. But this should show you basically how it's done.

Comment: Why do you recommend this way? I mean I stated that I wanted to use AutoMapper :(

Comment: Not to disagree with you, but you did not say that you wanted to use AutoMapper, only that you came across the article about AutoMapper. You said **"I want to make the application model-based"**. Having never personally used AutoMapper before I can't speak to it's efficiency. However, that being said I would be curious about it's overhead for so simple a task as building a method to convert a data table to a custom object. Is hutchonoid's CreateMap function really any easier to build and understand than my getPersonFromDataRow function?

Comment: It might not be as easy to understand having no strong mapper background. The thing is I actually thought of the kind of solution you brought up myself but as there are many different kinds of objects, it seemed unreasonable to create this kind of converter for each. As I said in another comment, I expected even easier from mapper but didn't get that. And it was clearly my mistake to expect that tags would be enough :/ anyway thank you for your suggestion!